# Call DisplayCurrentTime Enlightenment

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display an active time in label8 specifically, but I'm having problems in calling the `DisplayCurrentTime()` in the userform initialize.

*I am new to learning [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and I am browsing Stackoverflow for answers*

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Book2.UserForm1.DisplayCurrentTime
End Sub
```

i have these to try to call it

```
Sub DisplayCurrentTime()
    Dim nextSecond As Date

  nextSecond = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

  Label8.Caption = Time()

  Application.OnTime _
    Procedure:="DisplayCurrentTime", _
    EarliestTime:=nextSecond, _
    LatestTime:=nextSecond
End Sub
```

and i have these lines to work in label8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `DisplayCurrentTime` inside the UserForm module. Then you can call the sub as follows

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Book2.UserForm1.DisplayCurrentTime
End Sub 

Private Sub DisplayCurrentTime()
    Dim nextSecond As Date

    nextSecond = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

    Label8.Caption = Time()

    Application.OnTime _
      Procedure:="UserForm1.DisplayCurrentTime", _
      EarliestTime:=nextSecond, _
      LatestTime:=nextSecond + 1
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could place `DisplayCurrentTime` in another module. However, you are populating controls in the UF so you will have to specify the UF. The procedure below is fit to work for any UserForm.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    DisplayCurrentTime Me, "Label8"
End Sub
```

Sub below in another module

```
Sub DisplayCurrentTime(UF As UserForm, Cntrl_Name As String)
    Dim nextSecond As Date

    nextSecond = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

    UF.Controls.Item(Cntrl_Name).Caption = Time()

    'If the control you want to paste the date to is Label8 for every UF, use the commented out code instead..
    '..and remove ", Cntrl_Name As String" from this sub, and...
    '..remove the specified control in the UserForm_Initialize sub

    'UF.Controls.Item("Label8").Caption = Time()

     'Module1 is true in my case, edit to suit your project
     Application.OnTime _
      Procedure:="Module1.DisplayCurrentTime", _
      EarliestTime:=nextSecond, _
      LatestTime:=nextSecond + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried placing DisplayCurrentTime() as public in module1 but im having runtime error 424 object required.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Unless you're using `DIsplayCurrentTime` outside of the UserForm, placing that Sub inside the UserForm's module is perfectly fine.

Comment: @dystopia94 I have added an alternative which you can use if you want ``DisplayCurrentTime` to be in another module than the UF's

Comment: Thank you @TimStack. The last code was not having an error and displays the time but it is not updating the time automatically.

Comment: @dystopia94 set `LatestTime` to `nextSecond + 1`, and specify the module for the procedure. I have edited the code

Comment: Stil not updating. But i found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5649YiZjZM&t=14s wich is how I want the clock to work but without the use of a start button,

Comment: Thanks for the patience and help. I Found a working code here:              
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Do
    DoEvents
    Label8.Caption = Time
    Loop
End Sub

Comment: Not an ideal code, but good to see you got it working. My code not working is due to the arguments specified for the Sub. I still advise you to place the Sub in the Userform module, that would work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `DisplayCurrentTime()` procedure as [**`Public`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/public-statement)

```
Public Sub DisplayCurrentTime()
  'your code here...
End Sub
```

This sets the "module level" as externally accessible.

> Note, `Public` `Property` and `Sub/Function`  will be accessible to all outside in all modules and all applications unless `Option Private Module` is in effect

Answer (score 0):

Found this code here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5649YiZjZM

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Do
    DoEvents
    Label8.Caption = Time
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code works and does what I want. Thanks for all the help everyone @Tim Stacks and @Rawrplus!